# Does android create intermediate printing files like spool files in windows?

Tags: android, apk, android-debug, android-developer-api, android-print-framework

Our requirement is to develop a system that captures intermediate print file before it goes out to printer and read data from it for a record keeping solution.

Did it on Windows recently where we could read interim spool files before it reaches printer but we need the same capability on android devices too.

New to android so not sure how does android do it? How does android issue a print? Does Android too create an intermediate file just like spool on windows? Any pointers/leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Android is Linux, so I'd look into how Linux does it.  However I would be highly shocked if you could do that on anything other than a rooted device, as Android tends to keep tight security between apps.  This sounds like something that would be better done on a server standing between the user and the printer.

Comment: Thank you @GabeSechan for the inputs. It certainly helps.